# Unable to import data into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We are having an issue importing entries into a table on MySQL version 8.0.27-0.  I have been able to reproduce the problem with a simple example.  Kindly note that all privileges have been granted to the user.

First I created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE people
(
  id  INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name  CHAR(40) NOT  NULL DEFAULT '',
  age  INT NOT NULL  DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Then I created the file /tmp/people.txt, with the following entries:

```
1   William 25
2   Mary    37
```

There is no issue with permissions of the file because `system '/tmp/people.txt'` gives the following output:

```
mysql> system cat '/tmp/people.txt'
1   William 25
2   Mary    37
```

However, when I try

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/people.txt' INTO TABLE people;
```

I get the following error:

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/people.txt' INTO TABLE people;
ERROR 29 (HY000): File '/tmp/people.txt' not found (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)
```

The file `/tmp/people.txt` has permission 777, so I am not sure what is happening.

---

When I try  `mysqlimport soverflow people.txt` from `/tmp` directory, I get the following error:

```
mysqlimport: Error: 13, Can't get stat of '/var/lib/mysql/soverflow/people.txt' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory), when using table: people
```

Comment: All is explained in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html), and yes, you need to check more than  1 setting to get this working. Like [local_infile](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_local_infile), [secure_file_priv](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_secure_file_priv),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get mysqlimport and LOAD DATA INFILE working by changing the file user and group to **mysql**.